# Windows Authentication to Sql Server Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have an existing SQL Server 2005, currently I am using in Windows Authentication and Db name is Restaurant.
I know how to change existing SQL Server from Windows Auth to SQL Server Auth, but it doesnt locks the DB.
Is there any way I can change my current SQL Server to SQL Server Authentication so as if any one tries to open Restaurant(DB) it'l ask for authentication.
And also please tell me what needs to be connection string.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server recognizes two modes of security:

1. Windows Authentication
2. SQL Server AND Windows Authentication

If you want to enable `SQL Server Authentication` on already installed database to allow custom username and password then you have to -

1. Enable SQL Server Authentication
2. Create a new user account OR use existing `sa` user account
3. Set account password

**Enable SQL Server Authentication Mode -**

1. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the
   server, and then click Properties.
2. On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new
   server authentication mode, and then click OK.
3. In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.
4. In Object Explorer, right-click your server, and then click Restart. If SQL Server Agent is running, it must also be restarted.

To Create New Login ID - Refer [Create a Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx)

**Disable Windows Authentication Login for BUILTIN Accounts** -

Once you are logged in as `sa` (system administrator) with password (remember password as you are going to disable Windows Authentication for `Default Logins`), follow below steps -

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Expand the nodes to reveal your SQL Server instance
3. Expand the `Security` node and expand `Logins`
4. Right-click the `BUILTIN\Administraors` OR `BUILTIN\Users` and select `Properties`
5. Goto `Status` from left pane.
6. Check `Disabled` under `Login`

No one from the Administrators group will be able to access your SQL Server now.

Referred [MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsecurity/thread/cc3339b8-24f4-4e5a-ae2f-fd491e93864d).

**EDIT:**

To Use Existing Login account `sa` -

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;
GO
```

Connection String -

```
Server=SERVER\SERVER_INSTANCE;Database=Restaurant;User Id=sa;
Password=password;
```

Refer - [Connection Strings for Sql Server 2005](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

I would recommend to create a new account other than `sa` and set its password.

Comment: As I have not installed SQL Server in SQL SERVER Auth, then how would get the password ?

Comment: You wrote that - ` I know how to change existing SQL Server from Windows Auth to SQL Server Auth`. You have to login with Windows Authentication and enable the `sa` account or create a new account and reset the password.

Comment: @user1737641 - Follow above steps.

Comment: mesharam earlier you have mentioned something about removing admin account so that SQL logins only in SQL Auth mode.<br>
how ever was able to login via SQL Auth , but if i establish conection through Windows Auh was able to login, which is not wanted, so please guide.

Comment: First of all, you can not remove Windows Auth completely. Because admin users of machine on which SQL Server is installed are owner of the SQL DB. But you can access your db with Windows Auth or SQL Auth if the later one is enabled. I believe you want to use SQL Auth with already installed SQL Server. In this case you have to - (1) Enable SQL Server Authentication. (2) Create a new user account w/ pwd OR use existing sa user account. Follow these steps.

Comment: I did exactly what u @parag mesharam advised me to do, however,
main purpose of changing Auth is because, user cannot login into SQL Server directly and tamper with data, user need to know user name and pswd to login into SQL to change data.

Comment: I have altered the answer above. Follow steps under section `Disable Windows Authentication Login for BUILTIN Accounts`. This will disable the Windows Authentication for BUILTIN users of the system.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
use [master]
GO

ALTER LOGIN [username] WITH PASSWORD='yourpassword', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

ALTER LOGIN [username] ENABLE
GO
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).